# How to structure a forum index semantically?

Tags: html

A lot of talk about using HTML5 semantically has been focused on the structure of single article pages or lists of articles. Finding information on how to structure forum indexes has been much harder for me (which is not helped by search engines not understanding what I'm looking for).

Reading through the spec I'd think something like this would be right:

```
<h1>Index Page</h1>
<main>
    <section class="category">
        <h2>My Category</h2>
        <section class="forum">
            <h3>A forum</h3>
            <p>This is my first forum on this website.</p>
        </section>
        [more forums]
    </section>
    [more categories and forums]
</main>
```

However, I'm not sure how well this plays with current tools that make use of HTML5 (e.g. the reader feature of various browsers, assistive technologies, etc).

Are there any good resources that discuss using HTML5 effectively for forum indexes and the like?

Comment: You may want to remove this line `Are there any good resources...` or people will flag for : "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Even removing that part, this could be considered off-topic as it is too broad and based on opinion